# Login.jsp not parsed with Spring security

Tags: parsing, authentication, spring-security

I am configuring spring security with my spring application.

The below is my httpsecurity configuration

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()            
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
```

Below is my login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="banner">Login to Security Demo</h1>  
    <form name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>"
                method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is now it is shown as is that is When login.jsp is hit, I get the source code . When I remove spring security config it works and parses the jsp page.

Can somebody point me the right direction as to what can cause this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring security `loginProcessingUrl` is set to `/login` in your configuration but your form action is set to `j_spring_security_check`.

Change your `<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>` to  `<c:url value='/login'/>` and your login should work.

Also, remember that unless you have explicitly disabled the Spring security CSRF token you will need this hidden element in your custom login form.

See [Springs documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token) on how to include this.

Comment: Hi Geditdk ! , Sorry I have not been able to try your solution. But I must tell you , the code you have mentioned  <c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/> is within the login.jsp page and will into action after I submit the form. But actually, my problem is, the login Page displaying source code i.e the JSP tags in itself as mentioned in question, so logically not sure if this will help !